# Validate tags using tagit

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I'm using the following tag-it plugin: http://widen.github.io/jQuery-Tagit/.

I would like to validate the tags, the input would be email addresses. How can I do this?

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="editOnClick" class="example">
    <ul name="email[]" id="email"></ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editOnClick > ul').tagit({
            select:true,
            triggerKeys:['comma', 'enter', 'space', 'semicolon', 'tab'],
            tagSource:"view_email_get_emails.php",
            editOnClick:true 
            beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
              return isEmail($('#email').tagit("tags"))}  

 });

function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
        });
        });
```

I added my code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pCHG/3/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: The tags are not really relevant for this question. You are asking how to validate e-mails in JavaScript, and that has [already been asked.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I would like to know how to validate the tags.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the email part from the question. But in that case an obvious question pops up: have you read the documentation? Have you tried the callbacks provided there? If they did not work, or you have problems with them, please add details.

Comment: @ Kapa Thanks for your help.  I'm very new to jquery, I have checked the documentation and tried a few things but I can't seem to figure out what to do.  I updated my code to things I have tried.

Comment: Please always add code samples of what you've tried in...just to show you have done some work on it if nothing else! Hope the answer helps. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the `tagsChanged` callback to detect when a new tag has been added, and then validate, and remove it if not valid. I see you've used `beforeTagAdded` - I'm not sure where you've got that from? But I don't know the plugin.

The below code does the job. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pCHG/5/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editOnClick > ul').tagit({
            select:true,
            triggerKeys:['comma', 'enter', 'space', 'semicolon', 'tab'],
            tagSource:"view_email_get_emails.php",
            editOnClick:true,
            tagsChanged: function(tagValue, action, element){
                if (action == 'added'){
                    if (!isEmail(tagValue)){
                        $('#editOnClick > ul').tagit("remove", 'tag', tagValue);

                    }
                }

            });


        function isEmail(email) {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            return regex.test(email);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much it's just what I needed your a STAR.